# Wifi Broadcast Message does not reach my Android phone but an iPhone

Tags: android

My `Samsung (S4)` is connected via `Wifi` (over a router) with a `PC`. Let's say the Samsung has  IP address 192.168.173.5 and the PC has i.e. 192.168.173.6

On the PC I simply do a network broadcast via an `UDP socket`. This broadcast does never reach my android world.

If I connect an `iphone` to the same network the network broadcast to 192.168.173.255 reach the `iphone`. I found something on the net that some `HTC android phone` does have this kind of problems - related to the `Wifi driver` on the phone.

**Question:**

Does anybody has an idea what's wrong here and why Android does not receive these broadcast messages? Is this the wifi driver on Samsung side which does not route broadcast messages at all?

Comment: Please post coding related doubt here. This is not a place to ask networking doubt. Please post your question in https://superuser.com or https://serverfault.com

Comment: This is, at least initially a software development question, until it is proven the problem is not with the program bring written.  You may need to take steps in your program to keep the wifi fully active, either see if there is a formal.mechanism or else generate occasional dummy packets of your own.  I have been able to receive UDP broadcasts on android over wifi, but only a minority of packets got through in an urban environment (broadcast traffic is UDP and so makes no guarantee).  In a rural environment the success rate was notably higher.

Comment: If I so send an UDP message directly to the IP address of the Samsung phone I always reach the phone but a broadcast never ever reaches the phone.